# which .Net framework support interop . redemption dll ver=5.18?

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

when i am setting **Target .Net Framework** to 3.5 and build the solution, it was showing [System.Bad_Image_Format Exception:'Could not load file or assembly 'interop.Redemption,Version=5.18.0.0'']

Answer (score 0):

Interops are version agnostic. You need to re-add the reference to the project. Make sure the bitness of the reference assembly corresponds to your project's one.